# Keycloak doesnt validate token on user_info endpoint in docker settings

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

My application based on microservices were working fine working on just localhost untill trying to set it up on docker-compose.
I've got issue on API Gateway side.  I've figured that authorization-uri has to be on localhost since it goes from outside of docker network.
token-uri and  user-info-uri are going from gateway to keycloak and need to call keycloak by its dns name. clientId and userId null in the error.

```
19:09:20,616 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=cinema, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.21.0.9, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Gateway
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://${ConfigService:configserver}:8888
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
            token-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK:localhost}:8080/auth/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            user-info-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK:localhost}:8080/auth/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK:localhost}:8080/auth/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            user-info-authentication-method: header
        registration:

          keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
            provider: keycloak-spring-gateway-client
            client-id: gateway
            client-secret: ${GATEWAY_SECRET:PxY64IIOcSCUgZDWRdt2rHf8SL41xdX5}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8890/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
            scope: openid
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

I've tried to change user-id to user_Id, but doesnt change anything.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same error in the console of my AWS Setup. Any help woul be really nice.